# i have row number and dataGrid with CheckBox column, how i can check if the row is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row

i have dataGrid (not dataGridView) and the first column is a check box. 
i have int number, and i want to check if the row in this number is checked or not.

how i can do this?

its the code i wrote,  myGridName is the DataGrid name.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int rowNum;

    for (rowNum = 0; rowNum < myGridName.Items.Count; rowNum++ )
    {

        if (  myGridName[rowNum].BoolPropertyBoundToCheckBox == true)    
        {
          // function on the checked row
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yuvaldayn it will be easier for you to iterate through your list (your `ItemSource`) and pick item where `BoolPropertyBoundToCheckBox` is true

Comment: I cam do that? 
The list does not contain field if it is checked or not. It contains the rest of the columns in the table.

Comment: You said you have _BoolPropertyBoundToCheckBox_. If that's the case, and you have checked state bound to some property in your object then you should have state of `CheckBox` in your object